# Android databases are too big to be created on onCreate

Tags: android, database

On my app I make use of two datatabases.

This is the class that handles the database management and all the query that are made to it.

```
public class Database {

    private DbHelper DBHelper;
    private final Context Context;
    private SQLiteDatabase MyDBone, MyDBtwo;
    static Context ctx;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DbHelper(Context context, String dbName, int dbVersion) {
            super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            // This is where the two databases are created                  
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVesion) {
            // database upgrades are handled here
            }
        }
    }

    // database constructor
    public Database(Context c) {
        Context = c;
        ctx = c;
    }

    // database open
    public Database open() throws SQLException {

            DBHelper = new DbHelper(Context, BD_NAME, BD_VERSION);
            // I have here some if code to decide witch one of the bellow is used
            if{
            MyDBone = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            } else{
            MyDBtwo = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }

        return this;
    }

    // database close
    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getData(........) {

        // My querys are made here

    }
}
```

My problem is that the databases are too big. In the onCreate method I'm getting the error: `The code of method onCreate(SQLiteDatabase) is exceeding the 65535bytes limit`. On the other side, my app is getting very big on size.

I would like to know what's the best way to address this issue since I can't change my databases.
Since my app must be run offline I can't make query's on a webserver.

I beleive that the best aproach would be to, on the first run of the app, download the databases from somewhere on the internet (drive, dropbox or other side) but since my programming skils are a little green I must pospone this to a must do in the future.

Is it possible, maintaining my Database class, prepack the apk with the databases and install them on the sdcard? On the other side this will increase the apk size (the total of the databases is 15 mb).

Please advise on the best way to address this issue.

Regards,

favolas

Comment: It's not the database issue, but rather the issue with the limit of a method size on Dalvik. You could just refactor your code.

Comment: I think you can put a .db file in your assets instead of creating it on the fly

Comment: @iccthedral Thanks. What you said was to create, inside `onCreate` two functions and then put the database one code in one function and the database two code inside other function?

Comment: @NathanZ Ok. And after that, moving the db to the sdcard, is it possible to delete the original db from assets? Sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: @iccthedral if the db don't grows, it's a possible solution. Thanks. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yeah. Load the data from a file. If there's a pattern to it even better. Put it in a loop.

Comment: @iccthedral Ok. That's a good idea. Another question. Can I create my bd programmatically using `onCreate` but set the destination location path on some location on sdcard?